# Получения всех методов класс

Tags: php, рефлексия

Получаю через Reflection все публичные методы определенного класса. Но он вытягивает методы и из классов наследников, как мне сделать что бы получал только методы данного класса который был указан ?

```
 $ref = new \ReflectionClass('nameSpace');
$methods[] = $ref->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
```

Comment: Класс не знает о своих __наследниках__. О __родителях__ знает, о наследниках нет. Можно попробовать отфильтровать полученные методы с помощью https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reflectionmethod.getdeclaringclass.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class A {
    public function method1() {

    }

    public function method2() {

    }
}

class B extends A {

    public function method3() {

    }

    public function method4() {

    }
}

$class = new ReflectionClass('A');

foreach($class->getMethods() as $m) {
    if($m->getDeclaringClass()->getName() === $class->getName()) {
        echo $m->getName(), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Выведет:

```
method1
method2
```

Вместо `echo` делайте то, что вам необходимо.

Comment: судя по задаче и реализации над было передать `B` и получить ответом `method3/4`

Comment: @teran с `B` тоже работает, я проверял

Comment: я догадываюсь, что работает :) вопрос просто был про то, чтобы исключить методы родительского класса, а вы показываете на примере, у которого нет родителя

Comment: @teran "методы и из классов наследников" мне всё же кажется, что я правильный класс указал

Comment: @teran Все таки прав)